# using list comprehensions for haversine formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, haversine

i have two dataframes. One of house locations, and one of restaurant locations, all with their coordinates in lat/lon. I need to create a new column that calculates the distance between all of them. for example, if i have a list of 5 house locations, the expected outcome would be 5 calculations for distance for each restaurant (25 values). df1 are the locations, df2 are the restaurants.

My distance calculation is here, but i did change it a few times:

Version 1:

```
def distance(location, restaurant): 
    lat1, lon1 = location
    lat2, lon2 = restaurant
    radius = 6371 *1000# km
    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c
    return d
```

Version 2:

```
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    radius = 6371 
    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c
    return d
```

I've tried writing a loop, but it returned 'Series object is not callable' error:

```
ll = [] 
for index,rows in df2.iterrows():
        lat1 = rows['Latitude']
        lon1 = rows['Longitude']
        for i,r in df1.iterrows():
                dist = distance((lat1,lon1),(r['Latitude'],r['Longitude']))
                ll.append(rows(float(dist)))
```

I then tried using list comprehensions, two different ways:

```
df1['result'] = df1.apply(lambda x: float(haversine(df1['Latitude'], df1['Longitude'], df2['Latitude'], df2['Longitude']), axis=1))
```

The first returns the error 'cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

The second doesn't give me the outcome i'm looking for:

```
Dist = []
for w, x, y, z in zip(df1['Latitude'], df2['Longitude'], df2['Latitude'], df2['Longitude']):
    Dist.extend([distance((w,x),(y,z))])
print(Dist)

output: [515.38848499753, 54.26312420254462, 10.563518031233743, 374.5045129388741, 451.6737920301973]
```

What is the right way to do this? Eventually I will have to scale it up to 100k houses and 2480 restaurants. Unfortunately, i do not have permission to share data.

Comment: When you scale that up, the result will have 248 million entries. You should probably find a way to optimize it -- maybe just do it by street or neighborhood, instead of getting the distance for every house.

Comment: `ll.append(rows(float(dist)))` should be `ll.append(dist)`. Why are you trying to use `rows` as a function?

Comment: @Barmar my mistake, i can remove that typo. & i agree, however, i am not in charge of this project and am only trying to complete what was asked of me

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert both your dataframes to float

```
df1 = df1.astype(float)
df2 = df2.astype(float)
```

The first method you tried should work now. In case it does not, here is a snippet that does

```
distances, empty_value_indexes = [], []
for i in range(len(df1['Latitude'])):
    try: 
        d = haversine(df1['Latitude'][i], df1['Longitude'][i], df2['Latitude'][i], df2['Longitude'][i])
        distances.append(d)
    except KeyError as e:
        print("Encounted KeyError in the {i}'th iteration, appending 0 to list")
        distances.append(0)
        empty_values_indexes.append(i)
    except Exception as e:
        print(d"Encountered a different error message - \n{str(e)}")
        


df1['results'] = results
print(f"Indexes of empty Values: {empty_values_indexes}")
```

Comment: I like your second snippet you provided, but it returns "key error: 5".  I also got my first method to work, but it returns the distances as a list, and i'd like it returned as another column in the df1. Advise?

Comment: The last line in the snippet `>>>df1['results'] = results` should make a column with the list as its values. As for the key error, I did not come across it. It might be that your dataframe has empty values. I'll update the snippet to handle such areas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectorized operations which run much faster, here's a snippet that takes two arrays of dimensions nX2, mX2, i.e. hold n and m locations

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances


def haversine(locations1, locations2):
    locations1 = np.deg2rad(locations1)
    locations2 = np.deg2rad(locations2)
    return haversine_distances(locations1, locations2) * 6371000
```

Using your dimensions it runs on my machine in 10 seconds

Comment: i don't have the ability to import this package on my computer

Comment: This is a more robust solution, and possibly one that has a faster execution time if you plan to scale this script on larger dataframes. I would recommend you install scikit-learn in your virtual environment if possible.

Comment: @PreciXon I just received permission to use this package and will move forward with this option, but i am still not seeing the right output, i feel as thought im missing something

Comment: Try changing `>>>haversine_distances(locations1, locations2)` to `>>>haversine_distances([locations1, locations2])`

Comment: @amanda I just tried using this code and it gives me an error saying that the inputs have wrong dimensions. I'm quite sure you have missing values in your dataset.

Comment: @PreciXon is there a way to account for that/ignore it?

Comment: @amanda I updated my answer a while ago to handle it

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# haversine formula
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    radius = 6371
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(np.deg2rad, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    total_dist = radius * c
    return total_dist


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat':[-14.345234, -12.456345, -20.111111, -15.222222, -16.111111],
    'lon':[145.632423, 143.653535, 147.111111, 146.222222, 148.111111]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat':[-14.345234, -12.456345, -20.111111, -15.222222, -16.111111],
    'lon':[145.632423, 143.653535, 147.111111, 146.222222, 148.111111]
})

# New column for df1, just a list of zeros
df1['distance'] = np.zeros(len(df1))

# Iterate over the rows of df1.
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # For each row in df1, iterate over the rows of df2.
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        # Calculate the distance between each pair of locations.
        df1.loc[index, 'distance'] += haversine(row['lat'], row['lon'],
                                                row2['lat'], row2['lon'])
# New column for df2, just a list of zeros
df2['distance'] = np.zeros(len(df2))

# Iterate over the rows of df2.
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    # For each row in df2, iterate over the rows of df1.
    for index2, row2 in df1.iterrows():
        # Calculate the distance between each pair of locations.
        df2.loc[index, 'distance'] += haversine(row['lat'], row['lon'],
                                                row2['lat'], row2['lon'])


"""
The above is a bit of a mess, but it does work. I am not sure how to convert it to a class method though.
"""
```

Comment: this does not accomplish the goal. i need distances from every restaurant to every location. that is 5x5 = 25, not 5x2 = 10